# Restore default trace mode adb

Tags: android, debugging, adb

In order to fix my adb setup I`ve set ADB trace mode to all using the following command:

```
set ADB_TRACE=all
```

Now that I've resolved my issue, I would like to reset the ADB trace mode to the default (out of the box) value, so my cmd output doesn`t get cluttered with unnecessary traces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is `ADB_TRACE=0`

You could try following:

```
set ADB_TRACE=0
```

Comment: pleased to hear that - happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn’t *completely* help me.
It did remove the trace, but also it gives this message after every adb command:
`Unknown trace flag: 0`

What actually helped me, was simply this:
`export ADB_TRACE=`